# How to get a clear Image quality on website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I took a screen shot of some text and table including figures on my screen to use it on my website. I pasted the screen shot on windows paint and save the image as jpg. when i use this screen shot on the website the image is blurry and content is not clear. any chance i can have a more clear image

```
 <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
    <img src="features/cest1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Overview" >
 </div>
```

Comment: Did you tried opening and check how is that image appears as original?

Comment: what quality setting did you use when you saved the jpeg? use a higher one, or save as PNG - of course, if the image is being scaled in the browser, none of that is relevant, it's possibly your browsers fault - which browser?

Comment: @AbhinawKaushik yes when i open the image on screen it looks good but doesn't look good on website

Comment: what does the class `img-responsive` does? is this the culprit? if your original shows fine, then as @JaromandaX says, if you are not `scaling` the  image it should appears as is!

Comment: Just for the fun of it, set a height of 100px and a width of 100px on the `img` element. Then tell us if the image looks clear.

Comment: i have the max-width: 100%; i changed that to 130px and it's better but still not 100% ok, i guess i only will have a clearness if the image is in its original size

Comment: 1) what are the dimensions of the jpeg? 2) what are the visual dimensions of the jpeg on the webpage? 3) what browser are you using

Comment: Windows Paint? Lol... he is the cause of your low quality image. This soft is forbidden to use for ages like 11+

Comment: @statosdotcom what do you recommend for the screenshots?

Comment: @JaromandaX the image is 1916 x 733 px and the image is sitting inside a col-md-8

Comment: `a col-md-8` that means absolutely nothing - so far you've answered 1 of 3 questions, clearly you don't need help

Comment: @sorry mate i got stuck with 3 people in the office asking me some stuff, the visual dimension, is that the size of the image on screen?

Comment: the browser is chrome

Comment: Dear @Sam: any little more professional image processing soft will do better than Paint. Have a look at GIMP, nice and free. If you are under Windows, there is also a portable version (no need to install): https://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/gimp_portable - Please, screen shot again, paste into a new file in GIMP, save as a JPEG with max 75 percent of compression and tell me what you find. If it will not be yet what you want, then the problem is the display of the image. We talk later.

Comment: @statosdotcom Thanks very much for the useful information and thanks for being positive and helpful

Comment: @Sam , my friend, you are welcome. Not one of us was born knowing everything! I've got curious about the **resolution** of your case, and image. Have you got a nice and cleaner image? You can count on me to continue on this matter. Thanks for your feedback.